# How to install ejabberd community version on Windows XP?

Tags: ejabberd

I am a bit confused the link to use to install ejabberd on my windows XP box [http://www.ejabberd.im] ? What are the steps involved and dependencies there off?

=====UPDATE=====

I installed ejabberd windows version from link as mentioned in reply thread - but when I started the app it stated:

```
Starting ejabberd...
./ejabberdctl: e:\bin\erl.exe: can't execute: (14001) Error 14001

There is a problem starting Erlang.
If the error you see is 14001, you need to install:
  Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 SP1 Redistributable Package
You can download that installer from www.microsoft.com
You can also check the ejabberd Administrator Guide
```

But even after downloading the package http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=5638 and successfully installing I still get the same error?

Please let me know how to resolve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could install 2.1.11 using the installer provided by Process-One [here](http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/archive/).  Windows installer for 2.1.13 is not there yet.

no additional dependencies are required as ejabberd installer includes a build of Erlang runtime.

But really I fail to see what's the problem with putting up a cheap box running some free OS (I'd personally recommend [Debian](http://debian.org)) where ejabberd would be installable via the OS's package manager, and will be upgraded along with the rest of the OS when the next release comes out.