# Ejabbered installation issue for Windows

Tags: erlang, installation, xmpp, chat, ejabberd

I tried to install ejabberd 2.1.11 for windows on my Windows system, but at the final stage of installation it given post installation error. Couple of some of the last lines in the intallation logs says:

***Executing final installation script
Error executing post installation script
C:\Program Files (x86)\ejabberd-2.1.11\bin\postinstall.cmd
./ejabberdctl: erl.exe: can't execute: (14001) Error 14001
Creating Uninstalle***r

Though the shortcuts are created on the system but trying to start the server gives following error

***./ejabberdctl: erl.exe: can't execute: (14001) Error 14001***

The VC++ 2008 is already installed on the system. While searching I found the following post on stackoverflow:

[How to install ejabberd community version on Windows XP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143080/how-to-install-ejabberd-community-version-on-windows-xp)

But this too did not help. Has anyone else encountered the same scenario? Your suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just for your information, We checked and found that we've VC++ 9.0 installed on our server, however it requires VC++ 8.0 SP1. But I guess that should not cause any issues

Comment: What happens if you locate `erl.exe` which should be installed by the time you get this error (into `%ProgramFiles%\ejabberd\Erlang` or something like this) and run it?

Comment: when i manrally locate and run the erl.exe, in the eventviewwer it says -   "Activation context generation failed for "C:\Program Files (x86)\ejabberd-2.1.11\bin\erl.exe". Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC80.CRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.4053" could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis."  Now I've both the vc++ 2005 and 2008 installed on the system, but still this error.

Comment: Are you sure you've also installed *32-bit* version of the 2005 runtime? I mean, judging from the pathname of your Ejabberd installation, it follows that it contains 32-bit Erlang runtime. Obviously, it won't find 64-bit MSVC runtime.